# Subdomain on the fly via .htaccess + hide subdirectory from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently I'm trying to have an environment that allows me to create a subdomain by creating subdirectory on the fly.

Directory tree,

```
domain.com
  ├── 1
  |   └── product1
  |   └── index.html
  ├── 2
  │   └── product2
  └── 3
      └── product3
```

.htaccess rule,

```
#Redirect subdomain to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA
```

Now, I have managed to use the .htaccess rule above to redirect me when I type in "1.domain.com" to reach index.html under subdirectory 1.

But if I go to "1.domain.com/product1" I will reach to my product1 page but the URL will show as "1.domain.com/1/product1".

How can I hide the "1" between the domain.com and product1 such that it will still show as "1.domain.com/product1" but in the background it will access "1.domain.com/1/product1" directory?

I have done a lot of research and found that usually people will ask to hard code the name of the directory but it won't work in this case because people will create subdirectories on the fly to get different subdomains so I will need a generic .htacess rule to handle this.

How can I achieve this?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite

- /product1

to

- /1/product1

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^((?!1).+)$ /1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hello, this seems to still show "1.domain.com/1/product1" instead of "1.domain.com/product1"

Comment: @avn what url are you going to?

Comment: I typed in "1.domain.com/product1" and it did show me product1 page but the URL is now "1.domain.com/1/product1". I want to hide the "1" in between domain.com and product1. And this is hardcoded with subdirectory 1 only? I need to be able to create a subdomain on the fly, there is no way for me to create 1 rule everytime someone creates a subdirectory to be used as subdomain.domain.com